# NavigationBar not showing when going to another tab in tabview

Tags: ios, xcode, scroll, swiftui, tabview

In my app when I navigate to another tab and scroll down the view and gets cut off and the navigation bar doesn't collapse as shown here:

[image]

I tried to put `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` but then this happens:

[image]

When I press the home button the simulator and navigate back to the app the navigation bar will collapse when scrolling as intended. Is this a bug with Xcode? Currently I'm using XCode 11.4.1, testing on an iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator but the exact same result occurs on my physical iPhone 6s Plus.

EDIT: The code for the tab view is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuScreen: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    var body: some View {

        TabView(selection: $selection){
            ItemsTab().tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                Text("Items")
            }.tag(0)
            TestTab().tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                Text("Test")
            }.tag(1)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Menu")
//        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination:ProfileScreen()){Text("Profile")})
//        .padding(.top,1)
            .navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
//        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct MenuScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuScreen()
    }
}
```

The navigation view is wrapped inside a splash screen like so:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SplashScreen: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    let content = ContentView()
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Loading")
                LoopingAnimation()
                NavigationLink(destination: content,isActive: $isActive,label: {EmptyView()})
            }.onAppear(perform: {
                self.goToContentView(time:2.5)
                }).navigationBarTitle("My app")
        }
    }
    func goToContentView(time:Double){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(time)){
            self.isActive = true
        }
    }
}

struct SplashScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SplashScreen()
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: I tried to put navigation views inside the tabview as shown here:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            NavigationView{
                ItemsTab().navigationBarTitle("Items")
            }.tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Items")
            }
            NavigationView{
                TestTab().navigationBarTitle("Test")
            }.tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                Text("Test")
            }


        }
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
            //            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .frame(alignment: .center)
//                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination:ProfileScreen()){Text("Profile")})
            //        .padding(.top)
            .navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())



    }
}

struct MenuScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuScreen()
    }
}
```

But while it resulted in a collapsing navigation bar that worked even switching tabs the result looked like this:[image]

Comment: can you paste code here ?

Comment: Are you showing the view controllers programmatically or using storyboard?

Comment: It happens to me when I hide the navigation bar from the parent's view. Is it what you did?

Comment: I'm using swiftui programmatically.

Comment: Is it because of how I wrapped the navigation view?

Answer (score 0):

Made the navigation bar stay collapsed in the tab screen similar to what happens when you navigate to other categories within a tab in the app store by setting `.displayMode` inside `.navigationBarTitle` to `.inline`

Screenshot:

[image]